# Neo4j Cypher query to find nodes with exact match (AND instead of OR)

Tags: nosql, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to create a query that bring me some node that have the exact match with a set of nodes. In this case I wanna bring experiences that have tags, for example, what experiences have tags: "food" AND "nightlife" AND "culture".

My query is "working", but bringing the result using OR instead of AND. How can I fix it?

I'm not sure if I'm using de correct approach of the

```
@Query("START experience = node:__types__(className=\"...\"), tags = node({0}) " +
  "WHERE experience-[:TAGGED]->tags " +
  "RETURN experience")
public Set<Experience> findExperiencesByTags(Set<Long> tagIds);
```

I'm using Spring Data 2.0.1 and neo4j 1.6.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to divide it into 3 separate MATCH phrases:

```
"MATCH experience-[:TAGGED]->tags1, experience-[:TAGGED]->tags2,  experience-[:TAGGED]->tags3, " +
"WHERE tags1.tag='food' AND tags2.tag='culture' AND tags3.tag='nightlife' "
```

Comment: I'm trying to do something more generic. I receive a set of tag IDs like parameter of this method and I must use these to create my "where" clause...

Comment: oh, i see now. can't you just simply divide the input tags set into separate definitions? instead of "tags = node({0})" try to parse the input tags array first into separate starting nodes - tag1=node({tagIds[0]}), tag2=node({tagIds[1]}), tag3=node({tagIds[2]}), ... until end of tagIds. than match the nodes as i wrote above (without the where/and clause).

Comment: I created a dinamic query follow the @ulkas suggestion and it works!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @ulkas

If you really want to pass in an arbitrary number of tags you can try this, but it will probably perform not as good as the explicit matches.

```
START tags = node({0}) 
MATCH experience-[:TAGGED]->tags
WITH experience, count(*) as cnt
WHERE cnt = length({0})
RETURN experience
```